# HTTP get Service returns empty array

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a HTML page where i am displaying list of patient. (list called from service call to json server). when user clicks on a patient,it should display the details of the page.

in the services

```
getPatientList(): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.get<any[]>(`${endpoint}/patient-details`);
}

getPatientDetails(id: number): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any[]>(`${endpoint}/patient-details? 
  profile_no=${id}`);
```

}
   }

patient-details.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-patient-details',
  templateUrl: './patient-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./patient-details.component.css']
})

export class PatientDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  patient : any;
  pId: number;

  constructor(private data: DataService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  ngOnInit() {

  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.pId=params.profile_no;
  });
   console.log(this.pId);

     this.data.getPatientDetails(this.pId).subscribe(
    patient => {
        console.log(patient);
       this.patient = patient;
       console.log(this.patient);
    });
}
```

console.log(patient) display a empty array always.

```
<div class="form-group child">
      <h1>{{patient.first_name}} {{patient.last_name}}</h1>
    <div class="col form-group form-control-md mt-5">
      <label for="profileNo" style="width:25%">Profile No: </label>
      <label></label>
      <input type="text" class="input-group-sm" [(ngModel)]="patient.profile_no"> 
    </div>  
    <div class="col form-group form-control-md">
      <label for="DOB" style="width:25%">Date of Birth: </label> 
      <input type="text" class="input-group-sm" [(ngModel)]="patient.DOB">
    </div> 
    <div class="col form-group">
      <label for="gender" style="width:25%">Gender: </label>
      <input type="text" class="input-group-sm"[(ngModel)]="patient.gender"> 
    </div>
    <div class="col form-group">
      <label for="bloodGroup" style="width:25%">Blood Group: </label>
      <input type="text" class="input-group-sm" [(ngModel)]="patient.blood_group"> 
    </div>
```

here is the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lpatyh

Comment: If you were not using `any` as the type of all your variables and return types, and instead use actual types, the compiler would be able to tell you what is wrong. That's why we use TypeScript. Define types, and use them. Avoid `any` as much as possible. Based on what you posted, the logged value should be undefined. It can't possibly be an Observable. Use types, then post your real code and your real output.

Comment: i can not set a fixed  type of patient object as every patient may have different field, based on the data provided by patient.

Comment: Can you `curl` the web service and get a proper response?

Comment: can you please guide me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your data service `getPatientList` and `getPatientDetails` functions. Looks like you're not getting the data correctly. Copy the `get` url of both functions and paste it to your browser address bar and see if you're getting a `json` response. Most chances that you're not getting this results.

I've forked your [StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-53989906) and modified this function to return an hard-coded objects as an observable. With this change you can see that the patient details form is shown.

**Update:**

Few problems in your code:

1. The function `private extractData(res: Response) { ... }` in `data.service.ts` doesn't get a `Response` object, it gets an array of your object literal. Change it to `any[]` (if you have a class object, change the `any[]` to it, e.g. `Patient[]`). **Make sure that your http get returns an array of objects**
2. In `patient-list.component.ts`, change your `patient` variable to an `Observable<any[]>`, assign it with the `getPatientList` result like this:

   ```
   this.patient = this.data.getPatientList();
   ```
3. Use it with `async` pipe in the template like this:

   ```
   <li *ngFor= "let p of patient | async">
   ```

I've updated the forked [StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-53989906) with this changes.

Comment: i see that.. i tried the get url in my browser and they both returns the json correctly.

Comment: I've found some problems in your project, I'm updating the answer